# Adding :hover programatically to multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

Is it possible to programmatically add `hover` to multiple elements? In our system, there are more elements representing a single unit (yet they need to be separated into more elements for other reasons) and in certain cases, they should all recolor together on hover. Is it possible to programmatically add `hover` to multiple elements? Resp. is it even good practice?

I can easily work around the issue by using `my_own_css_class` which will be added to all of them on hover. But it looked to me that making them `hover` programmatically could have some benefits for me (e.g. when leaving with the mouse out of them, I'd hope that the hover would get cleared, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

> in certain cases they should all recolour together on hover

I'm not sure if I understand well the question, but as far as I know, there are 2 possible solution for this, and both of them include using a 'my_own_css_class'

1. CSS approach

```
<div class="hoverable-element">Element 1</div>
<div class="hoverable-element">Element 2</div>
<div class="hoverable-element">Element 3</div>
```

```
.hoverable-element {
  /* Nothing */
}

.hoverable-element:hover {
  /* Recolour */
}
```

2. JavaScript Approach

```
<div class="hoverable-element-js">Element 1</div>
<div class="hoverable-element-js">Element 2</div>
<div class="hoverable-element-js">Element 3</div>
```

```
.hoverable-element-js {
  /* Nothing */
}

.hover-effect-js {
  /* Recolour */
}
```

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.hoverable-element-js');

elements.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    element.classList.add('hover-effect-js');
  });

  element.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    element.classList.remove('hover-effect-js');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, basically the second approach (JS one) is what I'm aware of. What I was looking at is whether it's possible to achieve the same without `hover-effect-js` element, just by manually adding `hover` to those elements so that I don't need to care about e.g. `mouseout` anymore and it's happen by design of `:hover` css attribute.

If that makes it any clearer:)